# how do I set heroku port number in spring boot gradle?

Tags: gradle, heroku, port

[image]

root dir - procfile
web: java $PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

resources dir - application.yml
server:
port: "${port:8080}"

I set above options but I found another ports
Is there anyway?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the port to `java`. The `java` binary is trying to find a class with that name:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 35913
```

So, remove it from your `Procfile`:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Java is a general-purpose programming language and does not know what to do with a port. It doesn't run a web server unless you tell it to. Instead, you need to pass it to whatever web server you are running.

You appear to be trying to do that in your `application.yml` file, but make sure to use `PORT` instead of `port`:

```yaml
server: port: "${PORT:8080}"
```

Environment variables are case-sensitive on most non-Microsoft systems.

Comment: it's very thankful answer. I did as you told me but port is 31179. 2022-08-09T23:30:25.028361+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-08-09 23:30:25.028  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 31179 (http) with context path '' so Is there any other way?